# Bashrc function case statement to import cases from JSON

Tags: bash, scripting, function, json

I'm making a .bashrc function to get me around the system faster. I used a case statement to state where I want to go.

```
function da() {
case "$1" in 
    home)   cd ~
            ;;
    eolas) cd /home/eolas/
           ;;
esac
}
```

I want to import the cases from a JSON file, example:

```
{
  "cases": {
    "home": "~",
    "eolas": "/home/eolas/",
    "jdan": "/home/jdan/",
    "kl": "/.kl/"
  }
}
```

I have search for a way to do this but so far haven't found one, is this possible in bash? And if so how?

Comment: Have you looked into `jq` or do you desire a pure bash solution?

Comment: will do look into it

Comment: Are you aware you can write `cd ~eolas` ?

Comment: How strict are you with the format of the JSON file? Could the list, for example, be turned into an array rather than a series of objects, as in `{"cases":[["home","~"],["eolas","/home/eolas/"],["jdan","/home/jdan/"],["kl","/.kl/"]]}`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not exactly elegant, but seems to work:

```
in='
{
  "cases": {
    "home": "~",
    "eolas": "/home/eolas/",
    "jdan": "/home/jdan/",
    "kl": "/.kl/"
  }
}
'

case="$(echo "$in" |
          perl -pe 's/"cases". \{/case "\$1" in/;
                    s/: /) eval cd /;
                    s/,/;;/;
                    s/[{}]//g')"

eval "
  function da() {
      $case
    esac
  }
"
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a JSON file, automatically you should think about using [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) to parse it.

You'll want to read that file into an associative array:

```bsh
declare -A __dirmap
while IFS=$'\t' read -r name dir; do
    [[ $dir == "~" ]] && __dirmap[$name]=$HOME || __dirmap[$name]=$dir
done < <(
    jq -r '.cases | to_entries[] | [.key, .value] | @tsv' file.json
)
```

Then the function can be

```bsh
function da() {
    if [[ -v __dirmap[$1] ]]; then
        cd "${__dirmap[$1]}"
    else
        echo "No mapping for $1" >&2
    fi
}
```

Comment: I find jq hard to write, someone can help tighten that up.

Comment: The `jq` expression looks fine for what you're using it for. A small caveat is that some esoteric labels and directory paths may end up encoded (like those containing newlines or tabs).

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to use your JSON to build a associative array of case labels and their corresponding directories. This could be done once in your `~/.bashrc` file:

```bsh
unset _da_map
declare -A _da_map

if [ -f da_map.json ]; then
    eval "$(
            jq -r '.cases | to_entries[] |
                   @sh "_da_map[\(.key)]=\(.value)"' da_map.json
    )"
fi
```

(Or put it in a separate `da_init` function so that you can call it whenever you change the `da_map.json` file.)

The `jq` statement build a number of variable assignment that the `eval` evaluates.  The `@sh` operator quotes the relevant strings for the shell.  For the given example, this would result in the following code being run:

```bsh
_da_map['home']='~'
_da_map['eolas']='/home/eolas/'
_da_map['jdan']='/home/jdan/'
_da_map['kl']='/.kl/'
```

The `da` function could then be written like

```bsh
da () {
        command cd -- "${_da_map["$1"]?No mapping for label "'$1'"}"
}
```

This uses the associative array that was previous created to `cd` to the directory associated with the given argument.  If no mapping is found for the given argument, the expansion generates an error:

```
$ da "hello world"
bash: _da_map["$1"]: No mapping for label 'hello world'
```

One issue with this naive approach is that it does not allow for tilde expansion (or variable expansions for that matter) in the values of the directories in the JSON file.  You therefore should write paths without the use of `~` and without variables.